# Introduce someone to something / something to someone?

Tags: sentence-meaning, verbs

What are the differences between the following to sentences? Are they all correct?

1. Jack introduced me the beautiful world of mathematics.
2. Jack introduced me to the beautiful world of mathematics.
3. Jack introduced the beautiful world of mathematics to me.

Answer (score 4):

Version 1 is incorrect, as "introduce" can't be [ditransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ditransitive_verb).

Version 3, using "introduce" (something) to (someone), is awkward at best.

Version 2 is good:

> Jack introduced me to the beautiful world of mathematics.

Comment: In support of your point about *introduce **something** [non-sentient] to **someone*** being "awkward" (non-idiomatic), there's [this Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=introduced+him+to+art%2Cintroduced+art+to+him&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cintroduced%20him%20to%20art%3B%2Cc0) showing that it's almost always ***introduced him to art***, not ***introduced art to him***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers ‘the program is a bid to introduce opera to the masses’

Comment: @EddieKal: Yeah - the general preference is as described (but it's nowhere near an "unbreakable rule" anyway). But some more "abstract" parties to an introduction *(**the masses, the general public, a wider audience,** etc.)* are normally mentioned ***second***, regardless of whether the *other* entity is non-sentient *(**opera**)* or a named individual *(**the young Mozart**)*. Not exactly sure how accurately one could define & describe that area where the general principle is completely reversed though.